# Putting Datepicker in a Dialogbox jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I really need some help! 
I would likte to create an inputfield and when my visitors click on the 
Inputfield the a dialogbox is desplayed. 
Whitin this dialogbox, i would like to implement a datepicker a form whith name, and phonenumber and a submittbutton.

I tried ti do this but i think i mixed up my code even more. 
Could somebody help me with the code for this kind of pickle? :)

My main concern is how to get the datepicker and form into the dialog box. I' ve created the datepicker and also the form but I don' t know how to write the code so that to put them into the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at jQuery ui plugin like [this one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).
if you want to use a [native html5 datepicker](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) just add the attribute `type="date"` to your input:

```
Birthday: <input type="date" name="bday" />
```